# Making a 2d 100x100 array splitted in to a 4 25x25 different output

Tags: java, c++, arrays

I have a 100x100 array, but i need to clearly show the difference between the 4 sides(topleft,topright,bottomleft,bottomright) besides using color to show the difference, how am i suppose to show that it is different. The catch is that i have to use the letter 'A' for the array output. I also am allowed to use only 1 100x100 array. meaning i cannot use 4 25x25 array. This is in c++, but java codes or explanations are also welcomed.
Something like this?
Sample output:

```
AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA

AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA
```

Comment: What do you mean by "show the difference"?  Do you mean just highlight the outside edge?  How are you displaying it?  Why is color not acceptable?

Comment: @Taegost Hi, thanks for your prompt reply. I have to show a clear difference in the array where the 25x25 points meet, this means that i have to have 4 smaller squares within the 1 large square. color has not been taught to us yet.

Comment: Ah, I see.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Taegost I have used 4 different methods to output the board, but after i use a endline command, my output will end up with 1000 lines as every line is a new line, instead of 500 lines as the topleft and topright are suppose to be together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If are looking to print the array separating each quadrant as shown in your question you just need to split the array into two length and separate it with space. Provided the size is an even number. Eg

```
int SIZE = 100;
int MID = SIZE/2;
char a[][] = new char[SIZE][SIZE];
for(char[] col : a){
    Arrays.fill(col, 'A');
}
for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
    if(i == MID) System.out.println();
    for(int j=0; j<SIZE; j++){
        if(j == MID) System.out.print("  ");
        System.out.print(a[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The idea here is iterate through each element and if any index is half way append an empty space. So if you set the size to 4 you would get like

```
AA  AA
AA  AA

AA  AA
AA  AA
```

C++ example

```
#include <iostream>
#define SIZE 4

int main() {
    int MID = SIZE/2;
    char a[SIZE][SIZE];

    //Initializing array
    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++) {
            a[i][j] = 'A';
        }
    }

    //Print squares
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++){
        if(i == MID) cout << endl;
        for(int j=0; j<SIZE; j++){
            if(j == MID) cout << " ";
            cout << a[i][j];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this seems doable, let me try to convert to c++ and ill tell you if i managed to do it! thanks for the idea !

Comment: i realise i cant get this done in c++, do you have another means of contact?

Comment: Its easily achievable in c++. Updated my answer. Its been a while since I have worked in c++. Hopefully this program works.. ;)